# How to release Planet Bike fender safety release tabs

Tags: fenders

I have Planet Bike Cascadia Fenders and wondered how the safety release tabs work. I recently bought replacements for them:

https://www.planetbike.com/store/products/bike-accessories/service-parts/front-fender-release-tabs-pair.html

I've read that they release "the front fender stays if debris is present in between fender and tire" but am not sure what this means.

Does it mean in the event of a possible crash? That is, the tabs break allowing the v stay to move freely? Or for maintenance? Instead of unscrewing the screws that keep the stay in place, one can somehow release the stay using the tab? Maybe both?

If for maintenance, how does one release the tab? I see no place where one might squeeze and thus release it. I do, however, see two small holes at the angles near the tip. I guess one might insert two small flat-head screwdrivers, push the clip's small teeth inward, and that might release the clip. That seems tricky, though, and not the right way to do it. Still, maybe it is.

The paper insert that came with them shows only how to install them:

https://www.planetbike.com/store/downloads/dl/file/id/47/product/0/fender_safety_release_tab_instructions.pdf

Would anyone know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only purpose of the tabs is to be the weakest link in the chain so that, if something gets stuck between the wheel and the fender, the tabs will break, allowing the fender to come loose. If you didn't have the tabs, the debris would wedge between the fender and wheel, locking the wheel and throwing you over the handlebars.

You never need to release the tabs deliberately. To detach the fenders, pretend the tabs don't exist and just unscrew the bolt that holds them near the axle.

Comment: Should one break there tabs, fixing the fenders to your fork using zip ties could serve a similar function

Comment: @user74671 **Could** serve a **similar** function. But what you need is something that **will** serve an **identical** function. Don't jury-rig safety devices: they're not safe. Especially given that the question already states that it's possible to buy replacements.

Comment: OK, thank you! Since the pack came with two replacements I thought I'd replace both. I replaced the broken one and will now just leave the other alone.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend releasing the tabs deliberately, trimming the tabs to slip out easily, or otherwise keeping them sparkling clean. After two years of usage, my tabs were frozen in place and did not release when I rolled over a soda can. I ended up in the hospital.

Comment: Welcome!   How did rolling over a can cause that?  Did it get stuck around the tyre, and get picked up then jam between wheel and guard ?

Comment: Is it possible to detach and reconnect the tabs so they'll be sufficiently attached?  From the other answer it sounds like they're break-away tabs.